# Bootstrap Responsive Navigation not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am student using Bootstrap 3 for a Rails project. Currently I am trying to implement a responsive navigation that comes with Bootstrap. You can view the project [here](https://canadianponcho.herokuapp.com/vehicles). If you resize the viewport to a mobile like resolution, the navigation is gone. What must be done to have it functioning with the mobile icon for the dropdown of the list?

This is what I have attempted:

1. adding the compiled and minified JS to my header

   ```
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>CanadianPoncho</title>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'main' %>
     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

     <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   ```
2. adding the collapse and navbar-collapse to my navigation(s)

   ```
   <!-- NAVIGATION -->
     <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
       <div class="container-fluid bg-gray">
         <div class="container">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-collapse collapse">
             <li>
              <% if current_user %>
              <p class="member-info">
                Hello <%= link_to (current_user.username || current_user.email),
                edit_user_registration_path %>! -
                <%= link_to "Dashboard", current_user %> -
                <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path,
                method: :delete %></p>
              <% else %>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %>   </li>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
              <% end %>
            </li>
            <li><input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." /></li>
           </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
     </nav>

     <!-- BRAND + INFO -->
     <div class="container-fluid content-buffer bg-header">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-3">
             <%= image_tag("pontiac_brand_footer.png", class: "img-responsive center-block") %>
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-9 bg">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-secondary navbar-left navbar-collapse collapse">
               <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
               <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
               <li><%= link_to "Registry", vehicles_path %></li>
             </ul>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you need to do here.

1. Add the menu that will appear when the mobile break point is reached.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

2. Collect the links you want displayed in the mobile menu. You do this by adding the `data-target` value in the button above to the `id` in the container with the links. Such as:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
...
</nav>
```

Comment: I believe this works. However, must I add an icon myself for once it is in the mobile view?

Comment: Bootstrap should display it automatically with <span class="icon-bar"></span>, but you can replace it with your own icon as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the classes applied to each of the menu and read Bootstrap documentation on the behavior of some of the classes. In particular the why/when/how the menus are collapsed and classes `navbar-collapse` & `collapse`.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Also: It's OK to use snippets of code from documentations - however understanding what they do is paramount in determining your caliber. Good luck.